# Configure the path into properties file

Tags: java, properties, jboss, dependency-properties

I have a JBoss 7 application server and it consists of a file logging.properties.
In the logging.properties file, the path is defined (hard coded) as

> com.import.uploadDirectory=C:\progra~2\Demo\test\jboss7\standalone\uploads
>   com.export.templateFile=C:\progra~2\Demo\test\jboss7\standalone\templates\GDV_HDI_Format.xls

double slash "\"is needed because it works for windows system.
Now i want to remove the hard coded path and make system's absolute path.

What I tried is:

> com.import.uploadDirectory=..\..\..\..\..\standalone\uploads

but still it's not working and I am getting a `FileNotFoundException`

Currently I'm in the location

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Demo\test\jboss7\modules\com\c4i\configuration\main

and logging.properties file exists in the *main* folder

Is there way to rectify it?

Comment: Uh? IIRC, you do not need to escape characters in properties (they are loaded "as is", you need that in a Java program to distinguish a `"` character from a `"` that mark the end of a literal). I would use `\` instead of `\\` (not that I think this is the issue with your question).

Comment: should i try  like this  com.import.uploadDirectory=..'..'..'..'..'standalone\\uploads?

Comment: use backslash `/`. It works on both windows and unix

Comment: com.import.uploadDirectory=../../../../../standalone/uploads. Tried this but its not workking  :(